# Is an infinitesimal patch of a curved surface flat?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, nonstandard-analysis

Consider the unit 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$.  Let there be an infinite cone with its vertex at the center of the sphere.  Let the symmetry axis of the cone intersect $\mathbb{S}^2$ at the point P within the cone.  My question regards an infinitesimal neighborhood of $P$ lying entirely within $\mathbb{S}^2$.  I want to know if this neighborhood is a flat disc or not.  Specifically, I want to know if I can properly establish a system of plane polar coordinates to describe points in the patch of the form $(r,\theta)$ with $r=0$ at $P$.  Obviously $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $r$ would be some fraction of the infinitesimal radius.  I don't want to use the spherical polar coordinates to analyze the patch.  I want to use the plane polar coordinates.

The Gaussian curvature $K$ is uniformly $1/r^2=1$ everywhere on the unit sphere.  If, in general, the Gaussian curvature is the ratio of the solid angle subtended by the normal projection of a small patch divided by the area of that patch, then

$$ K = \frac{\Omega}{A} ~~.$$

If the cone's opening angle is $2\theta$, then the formula for the solid angle of the section of the sphere within the cone is

$$ \Omega=2\pi(1-cos\theta) ~~. $$

From Archimedes we know that the area of the spherical cap of the cone is

$$  A = 2\pi R h $$

where $R$ is the radius of the sphere and $h$ is the height of the cap.  Let $\delta z$ be the infinitesimal height of the spherical cap formed by the infintiesimal neighborhood of $P$, and let $\delta\theta$ be the infinitesimal opening half-angle of the cone.  Then

$$ K = \dfrac{2\pi(1-cos\delta\theta) }{2\pi\delta z}  = \dfrac{ 1-cos\delta\theta  }{ \delta z} = \dfrac{1-(1-\delta\theta^2/2+...)}{\delta z} $$

If we take the usual approach that the product of infinitesimals is zero then

$$ K = \dfrac{0}{\delta z}=0 ~~,$$

but actually the quadratic term in the cosine expansion looks like

$$ K := \dfrac{\delta\theta^2}{\delta z}  $$

which is of the order of an infinitesimal and should not disappear.  So... I don't know... can I treat the spherical cap as perfectly flat when it the cap is only an infinitesimal neighborhood of the point $P$?  Thanks!

Comment: This can't be answered because it depends on what you compute on this patch. In fact you are asking if $\cos \theta$ can be replaced by $1$ for very small angles, and the answer is "it depends".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to know if I can establish a plane polar coordinate system in the patch.  (WIll add to main question)

Comment: This doesn't change my comment.

Comment: The $2$-sphere, as defined normally, is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3.$  It's obvious from the comments from the one answer below that this isn't what you mean.  Therefore, please define what you mean by $\mathbb{S}^2$.  In which non-standard world does it live?

Comment: @JimmyRankerman Let me be more clear.  The standard definition is $$\mathbb{S}^2 = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \|\mathbf{x}\|_2 = 1\}$$
but this definition forces a standard analysis since there are no infinitesimals in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or any subspace of it.  You need to define _in which space_ you are defining $\mathbb{S}^2.$

Comment: No, you're wrong.  The standard definition is the one I gave.

Answer (score 3):

The precise answer is: there is no such thing as an infinitesimal piece of surface. The concept of infinitesimal objects is a point of view adopted by physicists because it helps them think, somehow, but it has no mathematical existence. You would have to define them entirely, and then define a concept of curvature for such objects.

A more tolerant answer is: a standard sphere has constant curvature, and the only reasonable meaning to "the curvature of an infinitesimal patch" is what you integrate over the sphere when you compute its global curvature. Since it is constant over the whole sphere, and since you get something non-zero when you integrate that constant, it must mean that the constant is non-zero.

Comment: Perhaps you could criticize the standard definition that "an infinitesimal quantity" is a quantity whose absolute value is greater than zero and less than any real number?  I'm not sure what you mean when you say "no such thing" because clearly you can have a patch of all points within an infinitesimal distance of a point $P$.

Comment: @JimmyRankerman There is nothing whose absolute value is greater than zero and less than any positive number. Not on this side of standard analysis anyway.

Comment: Obviously my question about an infinitesimal quantity is not related to standard analysis Arnaud.  That's why you don't see a "real analysis" tag on my question.  I think you should see from the context that your statement about standard analysis is not relevant to anything pertaining to a disc of infinitesimal radius.

Comment: Yes, I think all of you can forego your comments about "Standard Analysis" since I am using the standard definition of an infinitesimal used in "Non-standard Analysis."  Obviously Standard Analysis cannot be used to tell anyone anything about infinitesimals, ever.

Comment: @JimmyRankerman If you really know anything about non-standard analysis and if your question really is about such a framework, then your question should include this tag and mention it in the body, because, well, that's not the standard point of view. You should not assume that people are going to understand that just because you did not add a real analysis tag to your question.

Comment: I disagree since infinitesimals do not exist in standard analysis, and my question is about infinitesimals.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of physicist's infinitesimality is that of zooming in on a specific surface point. And that $idea$ can be made rigorous, even to mathemiatcians. In fact, as you said, $K=1/r^2$. To start with you have $r=1$. But you could consider the generalization of that last equation as $r=r\cdot 1$, i.e. as a scaling of your unit radius by the factor $r$. And that factor $r$ here becomes the zooming factor. Accordingly you are looking for $$K=\lim_{r\to\infty }\frac1{r^2}=0$$ i.e. in the final limit of zooming the spherical surface indeed becomes flat.

--- rk

Comment: Thank you, helpful poster!  I am looking for more material about how my physicist's idea can be made mathematically rigorous. Specifically, I am studying an infinitesimal neighborhood of the north pole $N$ of the the unit 2-sphere (what is called the halo of $N$ in the sphere in non-standard analysis.) I have some structure defined in the halo, and I want to show that the largest hyperreal infinitesimal distances between elements of the structure become finite distances in the limit of the scaling factor $r\to\infty$. Any help or guidance toward relevant source material is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Specifically, I am looking to make rigorous the idea that an infinitesimal distance should approach a finite distance in the infinite limit of the scale factor.  Since I am using hyperreals, and all of $\{ \varepsilon,\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^3... \}$ are considered infinitesimal, I should clarify to you that I am only concerned with showing that distances in the halo of order $\varepsilon^1$ approach order 1 in the limit $r\to\infty$.  Thanks!

Comment: For instance, in the hyperreals $\varepsilon=\omega^{-1}$ so I can take the limit $r\to\omega$ to generate something like $r\varepsilon\to1$, but I am looking for the way to state this (or similar) purely in terms of standard analysis where don't exactly have the cheat identity $\varepsilon=\omega^{-1}$ .

Comment: You just would have to think of the "infinitesimals" as of very small but still finite numbers. Then it becomes clear, if you have a variety of infinitesimals like ${ε,\ ε^2,\ ε^3,...}$, that you only could use some scaling $r\to 1/ε$ if you would ask for a rescaling of $ε$ towards order of $rε\to ε/ε=1$. Thus you still would have $rε^n\to ε^n/ε=ε^{n-1}=0$ for any $n>1$.

Comment: Or even better I should have said in the last equation $ε^{n-1}\approx 0$ for any $n>1$, as this $ε$ still is finite, so very small. And only then you could try again to take your aimed for transition towards transfiniteness.